# Django when processing a list of model formsets on invalid form only return last of the list

Tags: python, django, forms, inline-formset

I'm trying to process a list of InlineFormsets on a Django TemplateView. Basically is a list of projects, retrieved by a query of the parent object that binds them together. For each project retrieved I'm gonna show a form for asking some values of increments and start dates and so on. I'm restricting to just one FormSet per project for now. The are two problems: on POST it appears that the forms are complaining about the parent instance (proyecto):

> (Hidden field proyecto) The inline foreign key did not match the
>   parent instance primary key.

Then when the form_invalid function is called, the template just renders one of the forms with its data(apparently the last of the list).

I'm guessing the first problem has to do with the instance object of the formset, but so far I haven't being able to find a solution to retrieve the formset list and assign again the instance object on POST.

I'm sure the problem its very trivial, but I can't see it through. I'm relatively new to Django and Python (currently using 1.11 and 3.6.3 respectively). I appreciate any help or hint you could give me.

This is the related code:

### models

```
class Macroproyecto(models.Model):
    nombreMacroproyecto = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False)
    descripcionMacroproyecto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    m2Macroproyecto = models.IntegerField()
    lote = models.OneToOneField(inmueble_models.Lote,on_delete=models.PROTECT,primary_key=True,related_name='macroproyecto')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Macroproyecto {a}".format(a=self.nombreMacroproyecto)

    def get_absolute_url(self):        
        return reverse('macro_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def show_proyectos(self):
        return self.proyecto_set.all()[0]


class Proyecto(models.Model):
    nombreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False) 
    descripcionProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    m2PorProyecto = models.IntegerField()
    macroproyecto = models.ForeignKey(Macroproyecto, related_name='proyectos', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Proyecto: {a}".format(a=self.nombreProyecto) 



class Venta(models.Model):
    velocidadVentas = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    porcentajeTopeRemanenteVentas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    velocidadUltimasVentas = models.IntegerField()
    porcentajeTopeInicialVentas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    porcentajeVelocidadInicialVentas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    fechaInicioVentas = models.DateField(blank=False)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, related_name='venta', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    volumenTotalVenta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4,blank=True, null=True)
    reajusteVenta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)
    volumenInicialesVenta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4)

    ## Datos de incrementos

    numeroDeIncrementos = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    ''' # Porcentaje Reajuste FACTOR INCREMENTO '''
    porcenReajusteIncremento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    tipoIncremento = models.ForeignKey(parametros_models.TipoIncremento, related_name='ventaIncremento', 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    porcenTopeReajusteIncremento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "Velocidad de ventas Proyecto {a}, {b} unidades".format(a=self.proyecto.nombreProyecto,
        b=self.velocidadVentas)
```

### Forms

```
class VentaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form definition for Venta."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Ventaform."""

        model = Venta
        # fields = ('',)
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = (
            'volumenTotalVenta',
            'proyecto',
            'volumenInicialesVenta',
            'reajusteVenta'
            )

VentaFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Proyecto, Venta, form=VentaForm, max_num=1,
            exclude=(
                'proyecto',
                'volumenTotalVenta',
                'volumenInicialesVenta',
                'reajusteVenta',
                ), 
            labels={
                'velocidadVentas': ("Velocidad"),
                'porcentajeTopeRemanenteVentas': ("%Tope Remanente"),
                'velocidadUltimasVentas': ("Vel. Ult. Ventas"),
                'porcentajeTopeInicialVentas': ("%Tope Inicial"),
                'porcentajeVelocidadInicialVentas': ("%Velocidad Inicial"),
                'fechaInicioVentas': ("Fecha Inicio"),
                'numeroDeIncrementos': ("#Incrementos"),
                'porcenReajusteIncremento': ("%Reajuste Incr."),
                'tipoIncremento': ("Tipo Incr."),
                'porcenTopeReajusteIncremento': ("%Tope Reajuste"),
            },
            can_delete=False)
```

### View

```
class ProyectoIncrementoView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'proyecto/incremento_ventas.html'
    # form_class = VentaFormSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.macroproyecto = get_object_or_404(models.Macroproyecto, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return models.Proyecto.objects.filter(macroproyecto=self.macroproyecto)

    def macroproyecto(self):
        return get_object_or_404(models.Macroproyecto, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def lista_ventas(self):
        proyecto_list = self.get_queryset()

        if self.request.POST:
            return VentaFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            lista_ventas = []
            for proyecto in proyecto_list:
                formv = VentaFormSet(instance=proyecto)
                lista_ventas.append(formv)
            return lista_ventas

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         lista_ventas = VentaFormSet(self.request.POST)
         if (lista_ventas.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, lista_ventas)
         return self.form_invalid(lista_ventas)

    def form_valid(self,lista_ventas):
        context = self.get_context_data()        
        if lista_ventas.is_valid():
            lista_ventas.save()
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(lista_ventas=lista_ventas))

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self,lista_ventas):
        """
        Called if whether a form is invalid. Re-renders the context
        data with the data-filled forms and errors.
        """
        print(lista_ventas)
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(lista_ventas=lista_ventas)
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("proyecto:indexProyecto")
```

### Template

```
{% extends 'plantilla.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block tituloPagina %}
    <title>Incrementos y Velocidades de Ventas</title>
{% endblock tituloPagina %}

{% block body_block %}
    <h3>Incrementos/Ventas por proyecto para: {{ view.macroproyecto.nombreMacroproyecto|capfirst }}</h3>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Debe ingresar la información por cada proyecto listado</h4>            
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for venta in view.lista_ventas  %}     

                    {{venta.management_form}}
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading"><h5>Proyecto: {{ venta.instance.nombreProyecto }}</h5></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">                                
                            <table class="table-responsive">
                                {{venta}}
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                Guardar
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock body_block %}


{% block js_script %}

{% endblock js_script %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer, used a workaround.

I staged the form that I was trying to render in several create & edit views/pages. Not in the same view as list of FormSets.

If find a solution will post it.

Comment: Since you've asked the community for help, may be you'd care to elaborate about that a bit more?

Comment: Sure, I simply broke the code and separated the forms I was trying to do with inline formSets